# Why did postfix deliver a bounce notification to a local spool file, when delivery to this user has been disabled?

Tags: email, email-bounces, postfix

My postfix configuration allows mail via several local_recipient_maps. However, delivery to "proxy:unix:passwd.byname" is specifically **disabled**. This normally prevents delivery to local unix users:

```
$ getent passwd | grep www-data
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/bin/sh
$ nc localhost 25
220 my.mail.host ESMTP Postfix
helo localhost
250 my.mail.host
mail from:www-data@my.mail.host
250 2.1.0 Ok
rcpt to:www-data@my.mail.host
550 5.1.1 <www-data@my.mail.host>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table
rcpt to:www-data
550 5.1.1 <www-data>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table
```

However this morning I noticed an email delivered to the local www-data mail spool file. Looking within, I see that:

- It was a message **from** www-data@my.mail.host, sent by a different host within our network, using my.mail.host as the smarthost
- It remained within my.mail.host queue for several days while attempting retries
- It then bounced
- The bounce was delivered to a "www-data" mail spool file on my.mail.host

So my question is: **why did this happen, and how do I prevent it from happening in the future?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Assumption

You said

> delivery to "proxy:unix:passwd.byname" is specifically disabled. This normally prevents delivery to local unix users.

So, I may assume that you remove proxy:unix:passwd.byname parts from `local_recipient_maps`. By default the value of this parameter is

```
# postconf -d local_recipient_maps
local_recipient_maps = proxy:unix:passwd.byname $alias_maps
```

And you change it to

```
# postconf local_recipient_maps
local_recipient_maps = $alias_maps
```

### Analysis

So why it reject normal mail but bounce mail still going through?

To answer it, we need to see the big picture of [Postfix Architecture Overview](http://www.postfix.org/OVERVIEW.html), especially when postfix receives email

```
                            trivial-
                           rewrite(8)
Network ->  smtpd(8)           |  ^    
                       \       v  |
Network ->  qmqpd(8)    ->  cleanup(8)  ->  incoming
                       /
            pickup(8)   <-  maildrop
                                ^
                                |
Local   ->  sendmail(1) ->  postdrop(1)
```

Postfix only consults `local_recipient_maps` when it checked email received via `smtpd`. Why? Because the checks was performed when parameter `smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient`  value is 'yes' or you set `reject_unlisted_recipient` in smtpd_*_restrictions (notice the word smtpd in both parameter's name).  See [man postconf](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html) for details of parameter. This check is enabled by default. That explains why your test email rejected by postfix.

[Bounce](http://www.postfix.org/bounce.8.html) is special email in postfix architecture. It generated internally by postfix to inform the (non-)delivery status report to sender. It flows [through postfix directly to cleanup](http://www.postfix.org/OVERVIEW.html), bypassing `smtpd`. So that's why `www-data` still get bounce email.

### Solution

Instead of reject it, you can send it to blackhole with [mailbox_transport_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mailbox_transport_maps) and [discard](http://www.postfix.org/discard.8.html) service.

To do this set mailbox_transport_maps

```
#main.cf
mailbox_transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/wwwdata-blackhole

#/etc/postfix/wwwdata-blackhole
www-data   discard:silently
```

Now, whenever www-data receive an email, it will silently discarded.

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot of sense. I switched employers and no longer have access to the server that was doing this, so I can't test it. However it sounds legit, so I'm going to accept it.